# How to find an anchor tag with respect to href

Tags: jquery

I have take pathname through

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

Now I have multiple tags

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/1">1</a>
<li><a href="/12">12</a>
<li><a href="/13">13</a>
<li><a href="/14">14</a>
</ul>
```

Now I want to find `<a>` with the `pathname` that I have extracted

I tried this

```
$("ul").find(pathname+" a").parent().css('background-color", "red");
```

I got error in console that invalid property /1, something like that. Can anyone help me out
?

Comment: `$('a[href="'+pathname +'"]');`?

Comment: $('a[href="' +pathname + '"]')

Comment: ... what @DarkBee said...

Comment: First, it should be "background-color" instead of 'background-color". Then See my answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi May be you can try something like this,
So if you will use proper selector and check if it contains the current path string.Hope this helps.

```
      <div>John Resig</div>
        <div>George Martin</div>
       <div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
        <div>J. Ohn</div>

      <script>
       $( "div:contains('John')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
        </script>
```

[Jquery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul").find('a href=["'+pathname+'"]').parent().css("background-color", "red");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it with `each` loop:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
$("ul li a").each(function(){

   if($(this).attr('href') == pathname ){
      $(this).css('background-color", "red");
   }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="/1">1</a>
 <li><a href="/12">12</a>
 <li><a href="/13">13</a>
 <li><a href="/14">14</a>
</ul>
```

**JQuery**

```
var pathname = "/13";
$("ul").find("a[href='"+pathname+"']").closest("li").css("background-color", "red");
```

[image]

**Demo** https://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/stdqgjcx/4/